# Regex to find repeating numbers between other numbers

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following array and need two Regex filters that I want to use in PowerShell.

```
000111
010101
220220
123456
```

Filter 1: the number 0 that occurs equal or more than three times.
I expect the following values after filtering

```
000111
010101
```

Filter 2: all numbers that occur equal or more than three times.
I should only see these numbers.

```
000111
010101
220220
```

With **0{3,}** I can only recognize numbers in sequence so i get only the number

```
000111
```

Is it possible to find repeating numbers that are between other numbers?

Comment: Would you please provide an expected output?

Comment: You do not need Regex : string[] inputs = { "000111", "010101", "220220", "123456" };
            var results = inputs.Where(x => x.ToCharArray().Where(y => y == '0').Count() == 3).ToList();

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I would like to have it solved by regex if it is possible

Comment: String methods are a lot more efficient than Regex.

Comment: @jdweng, You may be right, but I wouldn't know how to call it in PowerShell.

Comment: Any c# code will work in PS since PS is written in c#.

Comment: It is simple : $inputs = @("000111", "010101", "220220", "123456" );
$results = $inputs.Where( {$_.ToCharArray().Where( {$_ -eq '0'}).Count -eq 3});$results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you insist *to see the solution in regex*, look at this: `'(\d).*\1.*\1'`

I think this is comprehensible without further explanation, isn't it?

Comment: Well done. I got hung up on _counting_ the number of zeros / digits, which isn't actually a requirement here. For the benefit of any future readers who are less familiar with regexes, especially the [_backreference_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions) construct (e.g. `\1`) that isn't often seen in PowerShell code, an explanation of the solution can be found on [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/PjdH0b/1).

Comment: It is a dream, there is exactly what I wanted to have.

@mklement0 Nice tip with regex101, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- [Armali's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75208177/45375) is short and to the point (use `'(0).*\1.*\1'` for filter 1), and definitely the best solution for the problem at hand, given that you only need to know in the abstract *if* a given string has *3 or more* zeros / same digits.
- The solutions below may be of interest if you need to know the *specific count* of `0`s / digits, which, as far as I know, cannot be handled by a regex (alone)

---

Occurrence-counting variant of filter 1:

```bash
@(
  '000111'
  '010101'
  '220220'
  '123456'
).ForEach({ 
  $zerosOnly = $_ -replace '[^0]'
  [pscustomobject] @{
    InputString = $_
    CountOfZeros = $zerosOnly.Length
  }
})
```

That is, each string in the input array (enumerated via the [intrinsic `ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach)), has all chars. that *aren't* `'0'` (`[^0]`) removed via the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator. The length of the resulting string is therefore equivalent to the count of zeros.

Output:

```
InputString CountOfZeros
----------- ------------
000111                 3
010101                 3
220220                 2
123456                 0
```

---

Occurrence-counting variant of filter 2

```bash
@(
  '000111'
  '010101'
  '220220'
  '123456'
).ForEach({ 
  $outputObject = [pscustomobject] @{ InputString = $_; DigitCounts = [ordered] @{} }
  ([char[]] $_ | Group-Object).ForEach({ 
    $outputObject.DigitCounts[$_.Name] = $_.Count
  })
  $outputObject 
})
```

That is, each input string by is grouped by its characters using [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object), whose output objects reflect the character at hand in the `.Name` property and the number of members of the group - i.e.  the occurrence count for that character in the `.Count` property. An ordered [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) is used to report character-occurrence-count pairs.

Output:

```bash
InputString DigitCounts
----------- -----------
000111      {[0, 3], [1, 3]}
010101      {[0, 3], [1, 3]}
220220      {[0, 2], [2, 4]}
123456      {[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1]…}
```

E.g., `{[0, 2], [2, 4]}` in the output above means that the char. `'0'` occurs `2` times, and `'2'` `4` times in input string `'220220'`.

Comment: Your solution could actually be seen as a final solution, I appreciate your explaining it in detail, but I would like to see the solution in regex if it is possible.

Comment: @uragus, Armali has since provided a concise regex solution, which is undoubtedly the best solution to your problem (which is why you should accept it). I got hung up on needing to know the _specific count_ of digits, which you don't actually need. It is _that_ problem that probably has no regex solution. I've revised the answer to complement Armali's with showing how to determine and report the specific counts.

Comment: Your solution is longer but easier to understand than Regex from my point of view.